# Why does the Welsh men's football team take strange poses in prematch photos?

Tags: football, trivia

Why are the Welsh players placed in this asymmetric position, during the team photo before their matches?

For example, against Georgia in 2016, where 3 players stand while 8 squat:

[image: 3 (standing) +8 (squatting) against Georgia october 9th 2016]

and against Austria in 2016:

[image: 4 + 7 against Austria october 6th 2016]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been covered by [BBC Sport](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/37602025), with a working assumption that it is a in-joke by the team.

It is noted in the article, there are team photos going back to 2002 which have a "lopsided" nature.